# How are Digit Extraction Formulas Special?

Tags: number-theory

There are hundreds of similar looking formulas to the BBP that I've seen on the internet, but those are termed as spigot algorithms only.

Why is it that none of those other pi formulas can be used for digit extraction while the BBP can be used for this purpose?

Or is it that all of the formulas can be converted into digit extraction type formulas?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spigot_algorithm

http://www.mathpropress.com/stan/bibliography/spigot.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A spigot algorithm calculates the digits from left to right -- in particular, to calculate digit $i$, you are allowed to use the digits before $i$ to help you calculate digit $i$.

A digit extraction algorithm can calculate digit $i$ without having the digits before $i$. Clearly, a digit extraction algorithm is a spigot algorithm (but the reverse is not true).

For example in the spigot algorithm [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Algorithms/SpigotForPi.shtml), you need the "predigits" to continue getting more digits of $\pi$, so you can't convert it to a digit extraction algorithm.

Comment: Yes, so why is it that all spigot algorithm formulas can't be converted into digit extraction?  What makes the digit extraction formula special?  They both use summation and express the numbers as a fraction of polynomials, so why can't a spigot algorithm that isn't a digit extraction formula be turned into a digit extraction formula?